# Is there an equivalent to HTML.DropDownList that creates an unordered list in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller I use the following:

```
ViewBag.ReferenceId = new SelectList(_reference.Get("00")
   .AsEnumerable()
   .OrderBy(o => o.Order), "RowKey", "Value", "00");
```

Then in my view I use the following extension to create a dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ReferenceID", 
   null, 
   new { 
     id = "ReferenceID", 
     @class = "combobox2", 
     style="width: 150px;"
   }
)
```

Now I would like to change this to create an unordered list. Something like the following:

```
<ul id="categories" class="pane list">
   <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any MVC extension that can do this for me or is there an easy way I can code something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent, though you could write it on your own like this:

```
tagsList = "<ul>{0}</ul>";
tagsListItem = "<li>{0}</li>";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
list.ForEach(listItem => result.AppendFormat(tagsListItem, item.ToString()));
return string.Format(tagsList, result.ToString());
```

And you could fit the code for your needs (like adding additional tags, attributes etc.)

Comment: This seems like a good idea but I am not sure about how to write the extension. Can you tell me where I can find the code for @Html.DropDownList so maybe I can adopt that as a starting point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write your HtmlHelper http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs but the best ways is to browse MVC source code and learn http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#288014 or use a foreach.

```
<ul id="categories" class="pane list">
@foreach(var category in categories)
{
  <li><a href="#">@category</a></li>
}

</ul>
```

Regards